# jQuery search each word separately in attributes

Tags: jquery, html

Hope I'm explaining this correct.
I need to search each word from a Input and see if it exists in a attribute in a  `<div>`. This is what I have:

```
<input type="text" id="searchInput" onkeyup="filter()" placeholder="Search within results">

<div class="filterSearch" data-tags="evga geforce gtx 1060 03g-p4-6160 ">...Some DIV Info...</div>
```

jQuery

```
        function filter()
        {
            var searchInput = $('#searchInput').val().toLowerCase();
            $(".filterSearch").each(function() {
                if ($(this).attr('data-tags').search(searchInput) > -1) {
                    $(this).show();
                }
                else {
                    $(this).hide();
                }
            });
        }
```

Now this works perfect when I search for "gtx 1060" as the words follow right after each other. But when I search for "1060 gtx" nothing comes up. I need some help to search each word separately to see if it exists in the attr-tags like "1060" and "gtx" for example

Comment: Which is the expected behavior if someone writes 'evga 1060' in the input? It should match?

Comment: by *Then everything is still hidden*, do you mean that is what it does or what it should do?

Comment: That's correct. If any of the words in the Search Input matches the words in the attr-tags (shouldn't matter the order) the is must show it

Comment: @Scaramouche If the words matches the attr-tags, it should display it and hide all the other divs that doesn't match

Comment: just if one of the input words matches? for example 'potato 1060 peanut' should it match?

Comment: Everything in SearchInput should match. Even if its not in the correct order

Comment: <any of the words> or <everything>?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You said at least one of the words written into the input should match at least one of the tags of the div, right?

I am adhering to that, although that would not be the *regular* approach since, for example, input **evg** would not display `<div class="filterSearch" data-tags="evga geforce gtx 1060 03g-p4-6160 ">evga geforce gtx 1060 03g-p4-6160</div>`.

let me know

**EDIT**
I understood now that you needed ALL words in the input to match the tags, not at least one.
Try this.

```js
function filter()
        {
            var searchInput = $('#searchInput').val().toLowerCase();
            var inputAsArray = searchInput.split(' ');
            
            $(".filterSearch").each(function() {
                var show = true;
                filterSearchTagsAsArray = $(this).attr('data-tags').split(' ');
                
                $.each(inputAsArray, function(i, word){
                  if(word !== '' && filterSearchTagsAsArray.indexOf(word) === -1){
                    show = false;
                    return false;
                  }
                });
                if(show)
                  $(this).show();
                else $(this).hide();
            });
        }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="text" id="searchInput" onkeyup="filter()" placeholder="Search within results">

<div class="filterSearch" data-tags="evga geforce gtx 1060 03g-p4-6160">evga geforce gtx 1060 03g-p4-6160</div>

<div class="filterSearch" data-tags="bvga geforza gty 1090 103g-p4-6160">bvga geforza gty 1090 103g-p4-6160</div>
```

Comment: that is exactly what I needed! Thanks a mil

Answer (score 1):

You can use [Array.every()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/every) or [Array.some()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/some):

```js
function filter() {
  var searchInput = $('#searchInput').val().toLowerCase().split(' ');
  $(".filterSearch").each(function(idx, ele) {
      var tags = ele.dataset.tags.toLowerCase().split(' ');
      if (searchInput.every((eleVal, idx) => {return tags.includes(eleVal);})) {
          $(this).show();
      } else {
          $(this).hide();
      }
  });
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>


<input type="text" id="searchInput" onkeyup="filter()" placeholder="Search within results">

<div class="filterSearch" data-tags="EVGA GeForce GTX 1060 03G-P4-6160 ">...Some DIV Info...</div>
```